# How to find at least a complex solution of tanh function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, numerical-methods

I have a trouble with my research. After some calculations, I got an equation system　for tangential hyperbolic as below

$$k_1 \tanh(k_1 D)/(w- q U)^2 = - k_2 \tanh(k_2 D)/ w^2,$$
$$k_1^2 = q^2 - (w- q U)^2/c^2, \text{ and}$$
$$k_2^2 = q^2 - w^2/c^2.$$

Here $w$ is variable; $k_1,k_2, q, c, U, D$ are parameters. By taking square of the first eq., we may eliminate $k1, k2$ . I want to know when $w$ will be a complex number. We may given the values of parameters $q, c, U, D$ to find numerical solution. In this case $D, q$ are fixed and I want to find relationship between $U$ and $c$.

For example, if $D$ come infinity then we found $U < 2 sqrt[2] c$ will give $w$ is complex solution. But because I cannot get analysis solution for $tanh$ function and I am bad at programming language. I am looking forward for your help.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I edited your question, please check if it still captures what you wanted to ask.

Comment: As far as I can see all your equations fix $w$ but they don't seem to be the same. What exactly do you want to accomplish? Do you want to determine $w$ so that it satisfies all equations as good as possible? Or do you want to choose your parameters in such a way that the equations are almost consistent? You should refine your question. It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What parameters are fixed? It is imposible to determine analytically (and very tedious numerically) for which ranges of $q,c,U,D$, the variable $w(q,c,U,D)$ takes a real value.

Comment: MrYouMath, thank you so much!

Comment: HBR, I just changed a little my question! And here, $q, D$ are fixed